# I'm trying to display the result of a function using the onclick function.(javascript)

Tags: javascript

I'm still learning javascript, any help would be very appreciated!
Here is my code:

```
function queue(arr, item) {
    arr.push(item);
    var removed = arr.shift();
    return removed;
}
```

Testing Setup

```
var testArr = ["roller coaster", "horror tower", "big train", "space    maniac"];
console.log(queue(testArr));
```

This logs the results just fine. I can even loop all the results to the console

Then I use the following. trying to display the result in a button on the html page :

```
 <div id="queue1" class="gray1"> 
     <h3>Available Fast Pass Experience<h3>
     <input  id="button" type="button" value="Click to see your next fast pass                 available attraction" style="height:100px; width:380px;font-size:325px";     onclick= "queue(testArr.value = 'onclick= "queue(testArr.value = 'Your next fast      pass experience will be + queue(testArr)')";>
<div>
<input id="button2" type="button" value="Available Attraction"  style="height:100px; width:380px;font-size:325px;"/>
```

I used the code above and I got errors
I got this error :

Uncaught TypeError: arr.push is not a function

Comment: You're missing an argument to your `queue` call - you forgot to put in the `item` parameter in `console.log(queue(testArr))`.

Answer (score 0):

Your Javascript is malformed in your example. All the browser reads is the part between the double quotes.

```
onclick="queue(testArr.value = 'onclick= "
```

The rest of this is junk as far as the DOM interpreter is concerned.

```
queue(testArr.value = 'Your next fast pass experience will be + queue(testArr)')
```

You should specify in your question what you're trying to do. If you're trying to display the attractions one by one in the array, you can simply loop through the array and keep your current index stored in a variable.

HTML:

```
<div id="queue1" class="gray1"> 
     <h3>Available Fast Pass Experience<h3>
     <button id="button" type="button" onclick="window.clickButton();">Click to see your next fast pass available attraction</button>
<div>
<br>
<input id="output" placeholder="Available Attraction" />
```

Javascript:

```
var testArr = ["roller coaster", "horror tower", "big train", "space maniac"];
var currentAttractionIdx = 0;

window.clickButton = function() {
    var output = document.getElementById('output');
    output.value = testArr[currentAttractionIdx++];
    if (currentAttractionIdx >= testArr.length) currentAttractionIdx = 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yk3qug4L/1/

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot. But after it displayed all the array indexes, it becomes undefined. I want to be able to keep pressing the button and keep repeating the array one by one again and again.

Comment: Then set `currentAttractionIdx` back to 0 when it becomes longer than the length of the array.